# Solving initial value problem for system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have solved a 2 variable system for eigen values and vectors and we have the general solution in the form:

$Y(t)=c_1e^t\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -3
  \end{bmatrix}+c_2e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    -5
  \end{bmatrix}$

and we also given $x(0)=2, y(0)=3$

Which part of $Y(t)$ is $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, so that I can find the constants

Comment: Usually $x$ comes first, but you should check your course material to be sure.

Comment: @amd, yes my x comes first so.. my x(t) would be $c_1e^t\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -3
  \end{bmatrix} $ correct? And likewise $y(t)=c_2e^2t\begin{bmatrix}
    2 \\
    -5
  \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: No, typically, the convention would make it $$x(t) = c_1 e^t + 2c_2e^{2t} \\ y(t) = -3 c_1 e^t - 5 c_2 e^{2t}$$

Comment: @Moo, ohh i see now thanks!

Comment: $$Y(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{bmatrix}$$